# NX on windows 7 - disruptive screen configuration change

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, nx

I am using NX on Windows7. Windows handles 2 montiors. NX running on the main one. After the screensaver was running, I got the following NX message: `Disruptive screen configuration change. Restore previous resolution to use Cygwin/XFree86.` Clicking on Dismiss button has no effect. So only think I can do is to kill NX process, and reconnect again. Perhaps increasing the screensaver time would solve the problem - but I think this is just a workaround. Any suggestion? Thanks!